# Pydrive auth method not using LocalWebserverAuth

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, pydrive

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

above is a easy way to auth

but LocalWebserverAuth is not usable in the command-line environment ( no browser )

Is there any other way that I could auth in the command line?.......

the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html)  only list one method

Answer (score 0):

Using commandline auth.

`gauth.CommandLineAuth()`